# TypeScript jQuery promise not passing resolve parameter

Tags: jquery, typescript, promise

I am using TypeScript 2.3.2 in Visual Studio Code and I am fairly new to it.  I am using it to create a front end client for a SharePoint backend.  There is a SharePoint jQuery pluging called SPServices (http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/) that allows me to get a JSON object from a call and the method returns a $.Deffered() object.   The SPServices logic calls resolveWith() and passes it the results from the SharePoint query that looks like this:

```
var thisResult = {
      changeToken: newChangeToken,
      mapping: thisListJsonMapping,
      data: jsonData,
      deletedIds: deletedIds
    };

result.resolveWith(thisResult);
```

Here is my code for handling the resolution:

```
$.when(promise)
    .then(res => {
      let me = this;
      debugger;
     });
```

This is after several iterations of code attempts. "res" is never assigned and the context of this in typescript is the class, which I see when I hit the breakpoint in Chrome.  In console if I check "this" I see the object passed to the resolveWith() earlier.

All tutorials I have seen say that res should be assigned that JSON object in "thisResults".  Any idea what is wrong and why this won't line up?

EDIT:  After working with the answer below I went back for some additional testing now that I had a fallback plan.  If I edit the SPServices library and change it to `result.resolve(thisResult);` instead of `resolveWith(thisResult);` the object is properly returned to the lambda.

Comment: Where `result` and `promise` come from? Shouldn't they be the same? I think it should be something like `$.when(result).then(reply => ...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want this to be the calling context you should not use the arrow function. This is the case with callbacks used by libraries like jquery, underscore etc.You should probably just use a function instead of a fat arrow.

Comment: It's odd that the documentation for typescript stuff that I've seen shows fat arrow to receive the resolution object, but at least switching to a function gives "this" the context I need for the TS to still compile.